# Trying to add a class to a TD and Span in a auto generated table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a bunch of tables being generated from ASP but I do not have access to the code. I need to manipulate data in one table, specifically the first td and span of each row which has a class of "Date". Problem is they all have the same class value. Is there a way using jquery to iterate through the table and add append the class name with a number for the TD and Span???     example td class="Day1", td class="Day2 etc and the same for the span ex. span class="DayDetail1", span class="DayDetail2"

Here is a simple example of the table

```
<table name="Table1">
    <tr class="Date"><td class="Day"><span class="DayDetail">Day 1</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Event 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Event 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Event 3</td></tr>

    <tr class="Date"><td class="Day"><span class="DayDetail">Day 2</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Event 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Event 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Event 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Event 4</td></tr>

    <tr class="Date"><td class="Day"><span class="DayDetail">Day 3</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Event 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Event 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: so you want to add class to all the `tds` and `spans` in your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var ctr = 1;
$('tr.Date').each(function () {
    $(this).find('td.Day').removeClass('Day').addClass('Day' + ctr);
    $(this).find('span.DayDetail').removeClass('DayDetail').addClass('DayDetail' + ctr);
    ctr++;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table name="Table1">
    <tr class="Date">
        <td class="Day"><span class="DayDetail">Day 1</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Event 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Event 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Event 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Date">
        <td class="Day"><span class="DayDetail">Day 2</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Event 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Event 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Event 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Event 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Date">
        <td class="Day"><span class="DayDetail">Day 3</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Event 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Event 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3qot851m/1/)**

If you are having these classes `static` then you can simply remove them from your HTML code and if these classes are `dynamic` then use `.removeClass('Day')` and `.removeClass('DayDetail')` first and add classes to them . I can show you how :-

```
  var i=1;var j=1;

  $("tr.Date td").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('Day').addClass("Day"+i);
        i++;
  });

  $("tr.Date span").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('DayDetail').addClass("DayDetail"+j);
        i++;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Document ready
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var i = 1;

    // Add new classes
    jQuery("tr.Date > td").each(function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass("Day" + i);
        jQuery(this).children("span").addClass("DayDetail" + i);
        i++;
    });

    // Remove old classes
    jQuery(".Day").removeClass("Day");
    jQuery(".DayDetail").removeClass("DayDetail");

});
```